# Нужно ли обособлять определение, выраженное инфинитивом?

Tags: пунктуация, определения, инфинитив

Дано предложение:

*Если не получается произвести хорошее впечатление, то есть вариант(?) **произвести незабываемое впечатление**.*

Нужно ли обособлять определение и какой выбрать **знак** (тире,  двоеточие)?
Но какому **правилу** решается эта задача?

**Пример:**  *Его желание **всем нравиться** все-таки утомляет.*

Здесь вроде бы не нужно обособление.

Comment: Либо тире, либо двоеточие, либо ничего. Предпочитаю ничего. Это моë мнение.

Comment: Тире можно было бы. Но я бы ничего не ставил. // Когда читаю предложение, спотыкаюсь на "то есть", сначала кажется, что это союз.

Comment: Хотя нет.. Отвечу потом на ваш вопрос, выскажете своë мнение насчëт него.

Comment: Все рассчитано) Спотыкайтесь... Хотелось бы по правилам. Помогите!)  Я пока не знаю, хотя правила знаю. Honestly!  Даже Интонация не помогает. Тире – да, а двоеточие совсем нельзя?  Хотела инверсию применить, тоже not very, словосочетание не хочется менять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Если не получается произвести хорошее впечатление, то есть вариант произвести незабываемое впечатление.***

Несогласованное определение не требует выделения знаками. По [справочнику Розенталя, пункт 3,](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110) несогласованные определения, выраженные инфинитивом, могут обособляться только тире и только если между ними можно поставить союз А ИМЕННО.

Можно привести несколько примеров оттуда:

> Я шёл к вам с чистыми побуждениями, с единственным желанием — сделать добро!
>
> Но прекрасен данный жребий — просиять и умереть.
>
> Мы все одержимы одной страстью — сопротивляться.
>
> С батареи получен приказ — не отнимать трубку от уха и каждые пять минут проверять линию.

Так что не нужна ни запятая, ни двоеточие, ни тире.

---

Но, как известно, тире можно ставить в любом месте при необходимости показать паузу на месте тире:

*Если не получается произвести хорошее впечатление, то есть вариант — произвести незабываемое впечатление*.

---

Вывод: знаки не нужны, но тире можно поставить при необходимости показать паузу.

**ДОПОЛНЕНО.**

Думаю, двоеточие тоже возможно:

*Если не получается произвести хорошее впечатление, то есть вариант (какой именно?): произвести незабываемое впечатление* — автор показывает важность этого варианта, стоит пауза перед двоеточием.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.  Но в моем примере можно добавить "какой именно вариант".  А можно не добавлять. Так ставить знак или нет? Кстати, в ваших примерах есть одна особенность: там уже есть определение, а потом оно поясняется.  Данный жребий – какой именно.

Comment: @Sharon И тире, и двоеточие по сути факультативны. Автор решает, какие ставить. Вам какой вариант приглядывается больше всего? Такой и выбирайте) Или вам не это нужно, а то, какие знаки возможны? Лично я предпочитаю ничего не ставить))

Comment: Можно тире, можно двоеточие, можно ничего.

Comment: Нет! Мне это одному знакомому надо написать, и чтобы грамотно было. Выразительно, чтобы понял!  А выбрать не могу. (Про Буриданова осла помните притчу?)  Прежде всего не знаю: знак ставить или нет?  https://proza.ru/2021/05/03/1620

Comment: @Sharon Если хотите выразительно и грамотно, то я бы выбрал двоеточие. Предлагаю его. А притчу не слышал, честно говоря.

Comment: Двоеточие Розенталь даже не упоминает, это здесь скорее авторский знак. Но нужно четкое правило: когда требуется однозначное обособление, а когда оно факультативное.    Это что-то по грамматике и структуре оборота.  (А притча хорошая, она как раз о том, как выбирать.  Ее часто цитируют, иногда художественно оформляют.)  Поэтому я всегда говорю: в ответе нужно предлагать выбор, а не варианты.

Comment: Опять чат случайно предложил.

Comment: @Sharon Я всë же таки не понимаю, что вам точно нужно. Тут все знаки авторские, понимаете? И всë-таки, что вы имели в виду под _выразительно_? Какой выразительный вариант вам нравится больше среди трëх предложенных?

Comment: Выразительно? Это когда форма точно передает содержание.  Если я выбрала такую грамматику и структуру, то надо ли обособлять? Ведь форма изменится значительно,  расстановка логических ударений будет другая. Please,  мне бы однозначную форму with justification, and that's it.  А я потом выберу, если будет из чего)

Comment: Так я же обосновал все варианты. Или ещë что-то не так?

Comment: (1) Выберите один вариант в качестве однозначного или факультативного с обоснованием.  (2) Для факультативного выберите двоеточие или тире (тоже с любым обоснованием).  Если все варианты факультативные, выберите по вашему вкусу и предложите мне. Это же быстро, даже много текста не надо). В качестве вывода в конце ответа.

Comment: @Sharon Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Напишите в конце ответа ваш  однозначный вывод. Я рекомендую...  (1) Не обособлять. Или  (2) Обособить тире.  Или (3) Поставить двоеточие.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за выбор.  Мне нравится ваш вариант Дополнительный вопрос. Почему в моем дополнении  нет обособления. "Его желание всем нравиться все-таки утомляет".

Comment: У нас как бы  ролевая игра « профессор и студент» . Зануда-профессор не хочет ставит студенту «отл» и пытается его засыпать доп. вопросом.

Comment: _Его желание (какое?) всем нравиться всë-таки утомляет._ Обычное несогласованное определение, не требует обособления. Тире не требуется, союз А ИМЕННО нельзя поставить.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Например:  Его желание всех утомляет... – Какое  желание? Что ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: Я просто знаю, что ЗДЕСЬ необязательно обособлять. Вот как объяснить, не знаю. Знаю, что можно не обособлять, но как объяснить только...

Comment: Ладно, Максим, я принимаю ответ.  А это вам для хорошего настроения в качестве благодарности. Миниатюра (из жизни студентов): —  Ну как, сдал экзамен? — Сдал!  (Выходит профессор) — Ну, положим, это не он сдал, а я сдался.